# Running multiple tests from different test suites in a specific order using Jest

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have several test suites with individual tests running by jest. For example the following test suites and tests:

first.spec.js

describe

```
async test1
async test2
```

describe

```
async test3
async test4
```

second.spec.js

describe

```
async test5
async test6
```

How can I run selected tests in different orders? For example run tests in the following orders:

1. test1 test6 test4
2. test6 test4 test1

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.